# Does Postgres allow json[] or jsonb[]?

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

So l have been trying to find an answer on the internet with 0 luck.

Does postgres support having arrays of objects in a single field, e.g.

```
[
  {
    key: value,
    another: value
  },
  {
    key: value,
    value: key
  }
 ]
```

and saving this to a single field?

Also how would you perform the single `INSERT` or `UPDATE`

would it be: `UPDATE db SET value='[{ key: val }, { key: val }]'` ??

Comment: `json[]` would be an array of documents. You are looking for a document that contains an array - yes that is possible with `json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres supports any valid json values, including json arrays.
What you are going to use is a single json (jsonb) column, not a Postgres array:

```
create table example (id int, val jsonb);
insert into example
values (1, '[{ "name": "aga" }, { "gender": "female" }]');

select * from example;

 id |                   val                   
----+-----------------------------------------
  1 | [{"name": "aga"}, {"gender": "female"}]
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your definitoion of objects I guess.

You can use JSON: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html and insert unstructured data:

```
# create table test (field json);
CREATE TABLE
# insert into test values ('[1,2,3]');
INSERT 0 1
# insert into test values ('[{"key": "value"}, {"key": "value"}]');
INSERT 0 1
# select * from test;
                field                 
--------------------------------------
 [1,2,3]
 [{"key": "value"}, {"key": "value"}]
```

There is also support for arrays: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html

Comment: Cheers for the answer!